# Cache issue with http header in php

Tags: php, http, caching, header, browser-cache

I work on a php service that displays images. My problem is that I can not handle the browser cache properly.

This is the code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussel');
$expireTime = 7200;
header('Date: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).' GMT');
header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expireTime).' GMT');
header('Cache-Control: max-age='. ($expireTime).', public'); // must-revalidate ?
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime($path)).' GMT');
header('Content-Type: '.HelpersFile::getMIME($path));
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
header('Pragma: public');
$fileRessource = fopen($path, 'rb');
fpassthru($fileRessource);
header('Connection: Close');
exit();
```

And this the result in http://web-sniffer.net/:

> Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2012 21:21:25 GMT
>   Server:   Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3-7+squeeze3
>   Set-Cookie:   PHPSESSID=86m4rha4rvth4q8srrpg48t4t0; path=/
>   Expires:  Mon, 16 Jan 2012 23:21:25 GMT
>   Cache-Control:    max-age=7200, public
>   Pragma:   public
>   Last-Modified:    Sun, 15 Jan 2012 14:42:39 GMT
>   Content-Length:   223247
>   Content-Disposition:  inline; 
>   Connection:   close
>   Content-Type: image/png

And finaly, you can see the PHP service here:
http://spinephp.info/service/MediaLibrary/mediaWithId/1.jpg

If I load the file into Chrome or any other browser, I always get an 200 OK reply from the server and the browser never load the file from it's cache.

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong.
Does anyone have a clue for me?

**[Edit]**
To be more precise, what I want is that the client browser does not query the server at all during 2 hours. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate the `If-Modified-Since` header sent by the client. If the file hasn't been modified since then, you should send only a `304` response back.

You might be able to save yourself some code by doing a `301` redirect to the actual file and let the web server do the work.

Comment: The redirect would make any protection the script might be used for obsolete. It would be better to enable `mod_xsendfile` and then let apache handle the file download by sending an `X-Sendfile` header.

Comment: @Thief, not a bad suggestion. Could also create a randomly generated link to the file on the server and use that, deleting it after a day or so. Unfortunately, we don't know what the user's requirements are.

Comment: The service is use to protect files from user that are not logged in the application. The service also made thumbnail of the file if needed.

Comment: About the 304 response, I use it (with an ETAG) but I temporarily disable it.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: That needs a real symlink in the filesystem or another apache module - so using xsendfile is easier.

Comment: Garith, what's the issue then?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. Just don't hit F5, because that will force a refresh. To test it, simply click your addressbar and hit enter.

Parsing If-Modified-Since is an extra benefit, if you do do a real refresh.